# inserting values in a fckeditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, fckeditor

i am inserting values in fckeditor.

```
abc = Regex.Replace(FCKeditor.Value, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

but while retrieving it is showing content along with the tags.
where is problem help me out.

Comment: everytime I see that editor name, I always think its something else !

Comment: Is your goal to strip out all the HTML? I use HtmlAgilityPack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to do it. Its a HTML parser

Comment: I had to unlock the parental controls to view this question :(

Answer (score 0):

without fully knowing what your input is makes it a little hard but, what about a regex like

```
abc = Regex.Replace(FCKeditor.Value, @"<[^>]*>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: it is not working.on writing a c programme it is displayed like this. main void() { &nbsp;&nbsp; printf(&quot; hello&quot;); }